# Create PDF document from the angular page

Tags: angular, typescript, html2canvas, pdfmake

I need to create the pdf document of the angular page. I am using the makepdf and html2canvas library and the page is converted into pdf successfully, but based on system resolution, the result of pdf document is changed, sometimes the page is cutting down from the right side or sometimes having the height issue.

This is code sample

```
  appendCanvasElement(els, indx, pdfContent, filename, callback = null) {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector(els[indx]), {
      width: document.querySelector(els[indx]).clientWidth,
      height: document.querySelector(els[indx]).clientHeight,
      scale: 2,
    }).then((canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
      pdfContent.push({
        image: canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').toString(),
        pageBreak: indx > 1 ? 'before' : '',
        pageOrientation: 'landscape',
        alignment: 'center',
        width: document.querySelector(els[indx]).clientWidth * 0.45,
      });

      if (indx === els.length - 1) {
        let documentDefinition: TDocumentDefinitions = {
          compress: false,
          pageMargins: [5, 5, 5, 5],
          pageSize: 'A4',
          pageOrientation: 'landscape',
          content: pdfContent,
        };
        let pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition, null, null, pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs);
        
          pdf.download(`${filename}.pdf`);
        
      } else {
        indx++;
        this.appendCanvasElement(els, indx, pdfContent, filename, callback);
      }
    });
  }
```

I have separated the elements to split the page into multiple pdf pages.
This is code sample to generate the pdf of multiple elements.

```
pdfCreator.saveToPdf2(
      ['#report-header', '#report-body'],
      `myFileName`,
    );

saveToPdf2(els: string[], filename) {
    var pdfContent = [];
    this.appendCanvasElement(els, 0, pdfContent, filename);
  }
```